# Deploying React app with Parcel build on Github Pages

Tags: reactjs, deployment, github-pages, parceljs

I am trying to deploy a React app with Parcel on Github Pages.

I have deployed it but the app is not actually rendering on the screen. I don't understand what I am doing wrong.

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "pet-adoption-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "homepage": "https://github.com/junaidshaikh-js/pet-adoption-app",
  "scripts": {
    "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.{js,jsx}\"",
    "lint": "eslint \"src/**/*.{js,jsx}\" --quiet",
    "dev": "parcel src/index.html --public-url /pet-adoption-app/",
    "predeploy": "npm build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d dist"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/junaidshaikh-js/pet-adoption-app.git"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/junaidshaikh-js/pet-adoption-app/issues"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.16",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.13.4",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.13.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.16.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.13.5",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.12.13",
    "eslint": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.4.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.22.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.2.0",
    "gh-pages": "^3.2.3",
    "parcel": "^1.12.3",
    "prettier": "^2.4.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0"
  }
}
```

Here is the live deployed link: https://junaidshaikh-js.github.io/pet-adoption-app/

Here is the Github Repo: https://github.com/junaidshaikh-js/pet-adoption-app

Comment: The script and styles are not published. It looks like only index.html is there on the server. Parcel must have built everything, because  the file names are mangled, but the files are simply not there.

Comment: How can I fix it?

Comment: That `gh-pages` command publishes your dist to the **gh-pages** branch of your repo. Do you have this branch set up as your "Source" for GitHub Pages in this repo? Go to **Settings > Pages** to verify.

Comment: Yes, this is the source branch

Comment: The problem is that in **index.html** (the published one) your CSS and JS files are linked with the paths like this: `/style.e308ff8e.js`, that is they are expected to be in the root folder. But your app's URL is **https://junaidshaikh-js.github.io/pet-adoption-app/**, so **index.html** , all CSS, and JS files are located in the **/pet-adoption-app** folder. You need to configure Parcel so that it adds that relative path to all links.

Answer (score 1):

After hours of research, I found out that when you ae using `react-router-dom` > `v4` and deploying to a sub-domain (for example `//pet-adoption-appk` in your case) you have to provide a `basename` attribute on the `<BrowserRouter>` with the sub-domain value. in your case you have to pass it like this `<BrowserRouter basename="/pet-adoption-app">`

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1**

1. `git remote add origin [YOUR REPO LINK]`
2. `git add -A`
3. `git commit -m "Initial commit"`
4. `git push -u origin main`

**Step 2**

```
"homepage": "https://[USERNAME].github.io/[YOUR REPO NAME]",
```

**Step 3**

```
npm install gh-pages --save-dev
```

**Step 4**

Add a script in your package.json file

```
"predeploy": "npm run build",
"deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
```

Run the command given Below

```
npm run deploy
```

Comment: I have deployed the app but it is not working

Answer (score 0):

As @tromgy pointed out in the discussion, the root of the problem is that the generated `html` pages contain `/` characters before the url references to the various assets.

For example, if you have an html file at `domain.com/subfolder/index.html` that contains `<script src="/script.js">`, the browser will look for the script at `domain.com/script.js` instead of `domain.com/subfolder/script.js`.

If you instead remove the `/` (e.g. `<script src="script.js">`) the browser will look for the script relative to the location where the html file was (e.g. `domain.com/subfolder/script.js`), which is probably what you want.

Parcel supports a `--public-url` option to accomplish this (see [cli docs](https://parceljs.org/features/cli/#parameters) and [target docs](https://parceljs.org/features/targets/#publicurl)). By passing a `.` as a parameter, you can tell parcel to omit the `/` from the output. So your build script would be something like:

```
parcel build src/index.html --public-url .
```

(strangely, in your question, you showed a `dev` command that used this option, but I didn't see that code in the example repo)

Another thing to note is that you're using the unsupported v1 version of parcel. I upgraded you to v2 and fixed the issue above in [this PR](https://github.com/junaidshaikh-js/pet-adoption-app/pull/1).

Comment: Hey Andrew, I have made some changes and the app is getting deployed but not working fully. Can you check once again?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: You have the same problem in the deployed site - `/` in front of the URLs. Running `npm run build` on the cloned repo produces correct html output (i.e. without the slashes). One thing I noticed was that the deployed HTML and Javascript is _unminified_ (i.e. it must have resulted from running `parcel` (i.e. dev mode, which in your repo doesn't have any `--public-url` flags), instead of `npm run build`) Perhaps the problem is that the `predeploy` script is `npm build` (which is an internal command run as part of `npm install`) instead of `npm run build`, which is your `parcel build` script?