# Deploying Vite.js React build to gh-pages

Tags: reactjs, deployment, react-router-dom, github-pages, vite

I'm having trouble deploying my SPA application to gh-pages and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.
First, I build the project then I deploy the build directory to the `gh-pages` subtree of the same repo.

When I visit the [deployment URL](https://omar-labana.github.io/read-track/) I'm faced with a blank page.

[GitHub Repo](https://github.com/omar-labana/read-track)

My `vite.config.js`

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  base: '/read-track/',
  plugins: [react()]
})
```

Comment: What is exactly the problem? It’s not clear what you mean by “trouble deploying”.

Comment: @tromgy my apologies, when I visit the deployed link, I'm faced with a blank page. here is the deployment link https://omar-labana.github.io/read-track/

Comment: It looks like you're having a similar problem to this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70259224/deploying-react-app-with-parcel-build-on-github-pages). The URLs in your **index.html** need to be relative to **read-track**. That question was about parcel, and you're using vite, but it should give you some clues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hours of research, I found out that when you are using `react-router-dom` > `v4` and deploying to a sub-domain (for example `/read-track` in my case) you have to provide a `basename` attribute on the `<BrowserRouter>` with the sub-domain value. in my case I had to pass it like this `<BrowserRouter basename="/read-track">`